# Call object from another method definition

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c

I am using Arduino and I want to re-use a method defined in another class in another method from another class. The problem is that when I compile I get the following error:

```
**RV8523.cpp:29:6: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
   I2C.begin();        //init I2C lib
      ^
exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before '.' token**
```

More info: the class that I intend to write re-uses this [I2C library](https://github.com/rambo/I2C) to communicate with the RTC RV-8523. The first method I want to define is the RV8523::begin() and is basically a 1:1 copy of a similar method existing already in the I2C library ( I2C::begin() )

Structure of the program:

**RV8523.h**:

```
#ifndef RV8523_h
#define RV8523_h

#include <inttypes.h>
#include "I2C.h"

#define I2C_ADDR (0xD0>>1)

class RV8523
{
  public:
    RV8523();               // Constructor

    void begin(void);       // Method to stablish I2C connection
};

#endif
```

**RV8523.cpp** (here is where I want to re-use the method I2c::begin() existing in the I2C library:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#if defined(__AVR__)
#include <avr/io.h>
#endif
#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif

#include "I2C.h"
#include "RV8523.h"


//-------------------- Constructor --------------------


RV8523::RV8523(void)
{
  return;
}


//-------------------- Public --------------------


void RV8523::begin()
{
  I2C.begin();        // <-- I get the error here
}
```

**I2C.h** library imported from  [Github](https://github.com/rambo/I2C). I paste just the relevant part of the library:

```
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
#include <Arduino.h>
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#endif

#include <inttypes.h>

#ifndef I2C_h
#define I2C_h

    
class I2C
{
public:
  I2C();
  void begin();

};

extern I2C I2c;

#endif
```

**I2C.h:**

```
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
#include <Arduino.h>
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#endif

#include <inttypes.h>
#include "I2C.h"

uint8_t I2C::bytesAvailable = 0;
uint8_t I2C::bufferIndex = 0;
uint8_t I2C::totalBytes = 0;
uint16_t I2C::timeOutDelay = 0;

I2C::I2C()
{
}

////////////// Public Methods ////////////////////////////////////////

void I2C::begin()
{
  pullup(1);

  // initialize twi prescaler and bit rate
  cbi(TWSR, TWPS0);
  cbi(TWSR, TWPS1);
  TWBR = ((F_CPU / 100000) - 16) / 2;
  // enable twi module and acks
  TWCR = _BV(TWEN) | _BV(TWEA);
}
```

Comment: You have to call the method on an _instance_ of your class, not the class itself.

Comment: Hi CherryDT, thanks for answering so fast. Do you mean I need to create an instance of the I2C object inside my RV8523.cpp?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `begin` on the *class* itself, `I2C`. You have to call it on an *instance* of the class. I can see in the line `extern I2C I2c;` that there is supposed to be a global variable `I2c` that's an instance of the class, and the [library docs](https://github.com/rambo/I2C) also show in their examples that one has to call `I2c.begin()` (and not `I2C.begin()`).

So I assume you just missed the lower-case `c` when reading the docs.

Comment: Now I see what you meant. Thanks a lot, CherryDT! You have helped me a lot :)